# Always Overwriting custom Portfolio Backlog(initiatives) instead of adding

Tags: xml, tfs, backlog

My On-Prem TFS Version is `16.122.27319.1 (Tfs2018.Update1.RC1)`. I'm following [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/add-portfolio-backlogs?view=vsts) to create an initiative backlog in my TFS.

The output I want is like below (which having separate backlogs)

[image]

But I'm getting the initiatives overwritten my Features, like below

[image]

My ProcessConfiguration.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProjectProcessConfiguration>
  <BugWorkItems category="Microsoft.BugCategory" pluralName="Bugs" singularName="Bug">
    <States>
      <State type="Proposed" value="New" />
      <State type="InProgress" value="Active" />
      <State type="Complete" value="Closed" />
      <State type="Resolved" value="Resolved" />
    </States>
  </BugWorkItems>
  <FeedbackRequestWorkItems category="Microsoft.FeedbackRequestCategory" pluralName="Feedback Requests" singularName="Feedback Request">
    <States>
      <State type="InProgress" value="Active" />
      <State type="Complete" value="Closed" />
    </States>
  </FeedbackRequestWorkItems>
  <FeedbackResponseWorkItems category="Microsoft.FeedbackResponseCategory" pluralName="Feedback Responses" singularName="Feedback Response">
    <States>
      <State type="InProgress" value="Active" />
      <State type="Complete" value="Closed" />
    </States>
  </FeedbackResponseWorkItems>
  <PortfolioBacklogs>
    <PortfolioBacklog category="Microsoft.InitiativeCategory" pluralName="Initiatives" singularName="Initiative" workItemCountLimit="1000">
      <AddPanel>
        <Fields>
          <Field refname="System.Title" />
        </Fields>
      </AddPanel>
      <Columns>
        <Column width="100" refname="System.WorkItemType" />
        <Column width="400" refname="System.Title" />
        <Column width="100" refname="System.State" />
        <Column width="50" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort" />
        <Column width="50" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BusinessValue" />
        <Column width="100" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ValueArea" />
        <Column width="200" refname="System.Tags" />
      </Columns>
      <States>
        <State type="Proposed" value="New" />
        <State type="InProgress" value="Active" />
        <State type="InProgress" value="Resolved" />
        <State type="Complete" value="Closed" />
      </States>
    </PortfolioBacklog>
    <PortfolioBacklog category="Microsoft.EpicCategory" parent="Microsoft.InitiativeCategory" pluralName="Epic" singularName="Epic" workItemCountLimit="1000">
      <AddPanel>
        <Fields>
          <Field refname="System.Title" />
        </Fields>
      </AddPanel>
      <Columns>
        <Column width="100" refname="System.WorkItemType" />
        <Column width="400" refname="System.Title" />
        <Column width="100" refname="System.State" />
        <Column width="50" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort" />
        <Column width="50" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BusinessValue" />
        <Column width="100" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ValueArea" />
        <Column width="200" refname="System.Tags" />
      </Columns>
      <States>
        <State type="Proposed" value="New" />
        <State type="InProgress" value="Active" />
        <State type="InProgress" value="Resolved" />
        <State type="Complete" value="Closed" />
      </States>
    </PortfolioBacklog>
  </PortfolioBacklogs>
  <RequirementBacklog category="Microsoft.RequirementCategory" parent="Microsoft.EpicCategory" pluralName="Stories" singularName="User Story" workItemCountLimit="1000">
    <AddPanel>
      <Fields>
        <Field refname="System.Title" />
      </Fields>
    </AddPanel>
    <Columns>
      <Column width="100" refname="System.WorkItemType" />
      <Column width="400" refname="System.Title" />
      <Column width="100" refname="System.State" />
      <Column width="50" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints" />
      <Column width="100" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ValueArea" />
      <Column width="200" refname="System.IterationPath" />
      <Column width="200" refname="System.Tags" />
    </Columns>
    <States>
      <State type="Proposed" value="New" />
      <State type="InProgress" value="Active" />
      <State type="InProgress" value="Resolved" />
      <State type="Complete" value="Closed" />
    </States>
  </RequirementBacklog>
  <TaskBacklog category="Microsoft.TaskCategory" parent="Microsoft.RequirementCategory" pluralName="Tasks" singularName="Task" workItemCountLimit="1000">
    <AddPanel>
      <Fields>
        <Field refname="System.Title" />
      </Fields>
    </AddPanel>
    <Columns>
      <Column width="400" refname="System.Title" />
      <Column width="100" refname="System.State" />
      <Column width="100" refname="System.AssignedTo" />
      <Column width="50" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" />
    </Columns>
    <States>
      <State type="Proposed" value="New" />
      <State type="InProgress" value="Active" />
      <State type="Complete" value="Closed" />
    </States>
  </TaskBacklog>
  <TypeFields>
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity" type="Activity" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank" type="Order" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Feedback.ApplicationLaunchInstructions" type="ApplicationLaunchInstructions" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Feedback.ApplicationStartInformation" type="ApplicationStartInformation" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Feedback.ApplicationType" type="ApplicationType">
      <TypeFieldValues>
        <TypeFieldValue type="ClientApp" value="Client application" />
        <TypeFieldValue type="RemoteMachine" value="Remote machine" />
        <TypeFieldValue type="WebApp" value="Web application" />
      </TypeFieldValues>
    </TypeField>
    <TypeField format="{0} h" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" type="RemainingWork" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints" type="Effort" />
    <TypeField refname="System.AreaPath" type="Team" />
  </TypeFields>
  <Weekends>
    <DayOfWeek>Sunday</DayOfWeek>
    <DayOfWeek>Saturday</DayOfWeek>
  </Weekends>
  <Properties>
    <Property name="BugsBehavior" value="Off" />
  </Properties>
  <WorkItemColors>
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFCC293D" secondary="FFFAEAE5" name="Bug" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFB4009E" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Code Review Request" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFB4009E" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Code Review Response" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF7B00" secondary="FFFFD7B5" name="Epic" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FF773B93" secondary="FFEEE2F2" name="Feature" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FF004B50" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Feedback Request" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FF004B50" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Feedback Response" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFCC66FF" secondary="FFF0D1FF" name="Initiative" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFB4009E" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Issue" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FF004B50" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Shared Parameter" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FF004B50" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Shared Steps" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFF2CB1D" secondary="FFF6F5D2" name="Task" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FF004B50" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Test Case" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FF004B50" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Test Plan" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FF004B50" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Test Suite" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FF009CCC" secondary="FFD6ECF2" name="User Story" />
  </WorkItemColors>
</ProjectProcessConfiguration>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/add-portfolio-backlogs?view=vsts#4-update-processconfiguration-to-add-the-initiative-portfolio-backlog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have "Microsoft.FeatureCategory" on your process.

You need to add this section within the `<PortfolioBacklogs>` section:

```
  <PortfolioBacklog category="Microsoft.FeatureCategory" pluralName="Features" singularName="Feature" parent="Microsoft.EpicCategory" workItemCountLimit="1000">
     . . . 
    Columns, States etc.
   </PortfolioBacklog>
```